# Process by Redirect to Url

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, response.redirect

i have VB.net code behind like this :

```
   Protected Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button.Click
        Dim Adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim sql As String = "select House , OPR_BALANCE from vAgeLast where LEN(HOUSE) = 8 and OPR_BALANCE > 1000000 order by OPR_BALANCE desc"
        SqlConn.Open()
        sqlCmd = New SqlCommand(sql, SqlConn)
        Adapter.SelectCommand = sqlCmd
        Adapter.Fill(ds)
        For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            idCustomer = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("House").ToString()
            amt = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("OPR_BALANCE").ToString()
            lang = "0"
            aid = "000000"
            Dim result As String = "http://soap.Services.com:2121/WS.aspx/?c=1&id=" + idCustomer + "&lang=" + lang + ""
             Response.Redirect(result)

        Next
        Adapter.Dispose()
        sqlCmd.Dispose()
        SqlConn.Close()
    End Sub
```

in this code i want to process all the value from dataset result, which could only get by redirect to url, but when i run the code, it only run once.

is it possible to redirect to url without get feedback display on website?

Comment: If an exception is thrown, you'll never get to call .Close() on your sql connection. If that happens often enough, you can lock yourself out of your database. You need a Try/Finally or Using block.

Comment: how about when i got this line :  Dim result As String = `"http://soap.Services.com:2121/WS.aspx/?c=1&id=" + idCustomer + "&lang=" + lang + ""
             Response.Redirect(result)` is it possible response.redirect execute more than once?

Comment: Response.Redirect() **stops** your current page and sends you to a new page. If you have 20 records, what do you want the result of this to be? 20 tabs open in the user's browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it from other users.

Redirecting inside a loop wont work. You need to call the service in other way.
Try using `DownloadString` method of `WebClient`. Extract `result` by this:

```
Dim client As New WebClient()
Dim result As String = client.DownloadString("http://soap.Services.com:2121/WS.aspx/?c=1&id=" + idCustomer + "&lang=" + lang )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "Dim SqlConn As New SQLConnection"

Comment: how about when i got this line :  Dim result As String = `"http://soap.Services.com:2121/WS.aspx/?c=1&id=" + idCustomer + "&lang=" + lang + ""
             Response.Redirect(result)` is it possible response.redirect execute more than once?